# I accidentally typo'd "npm i npm" and it installed a bunch of node modules I didn't need. How can I revert?

Tags: npm, node-modules, uninstallation

I'm new, and I'm lost because I think I messed up my whole program. I cannot install anymore node variations. I'm using Visual Studio Code. And after the code below I typed "npm uninstall npm" thinking it would fix it, but it seems not.

I tried npm uninstall npm and it didn't work. :/

````
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of erlpack@discordapp/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.7.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of opusscript@^0.0.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of @discordjs/uws@^10.149.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js-commando@0.10.0 requires a peer of sqlite@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN westeros-bot@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN westeros-bot@1.0.0 No repository field.

+ npm@6.9.0
added 426 packages from 800 contributors and audited 12108 packages in 45.684s
found 12 high severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details```

AFTER

```c:\Users\madel\Desktop\Westeros Bot\dist>npm uninstall npm
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of bufferutil@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of erlpack@discordapp/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.7.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of node-opus@^0.2.7 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of opusscript@^0.0.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.5.0 requires a peer of @discordjs/uws@^10.149.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js-commando@0.10.0 requires a peer of sqlite@^2.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN westeros-bot@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN westeros-bot@1.0.0 No repository field.

removed 426 packages and audited 12 packages in 7.294s
found 0 vulnerabilities```
````

Comment: So how exactly it "doesn't work" now? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `npm remove npm` and run `npm install` to update package-lock.json file.